# Two way binding, shallow $watch, isolate scope not working together

Tags: angularjs

Please refer to this fiddle for the questions. http://jsfiddle.net/AQR55/

1) Why a watch that is attached to an isolate scope property - which is bidirectionally bound to a parent property, is not triggering on changing the parent scope property.

In the fiddle, the below metioned watch is not getting triggered, on changing the parent scope property to which it is bound.

```
$scope.$watch('acts', function(neww ,old){
                    console.log(neww)
                })
```

2) `ng-click="addaction()" addaction="addaction()"`. Can this code be put in more elegant way? Because, to perform an action in isolated scope, it seems we need to set bidirectional binding and the attach to ng-click.

3)Can i declare methods inside the isolated scope like shown below? If i do like this, I'm getting .js error.

```
<isolate-scope-creating-cmp ng-click="isolateCmpClickHandler()"></isolate-scope-creating-cmp>
scope:{
    isolateCmpClickHandler:function(){
      //If i do like this, I'm getting .js error

    }
}
```

Comment: why is the second point used?

Comment: I want to setup event handler for the button. As mentioned in the 3rd point since i cant set the click handler inside the isolate scope i had to make one of the function defined in parent scope as the click handler. To do this i'm using '&' to evaluate the `addaction()` in parent scope , and im using that parent scope evaluated property as click handler using 'ng-click'. If i remove `addaction="addaction()"` `ng-click` is not working. The fiddle you have updated for question no. 1 is not triggering watch onclick of the button. Please have a look into the firebug.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Question 1.
Since you are adding a item to the `acts` array, you need to set the third parameter in [$watch()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch) to true

```
$scope.$watch('acts', function (neww, old) {
    console.log(neww)
}, true);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gM2Hg/)

Question 2. 
Since there is an isolated scope, you need to call the `$parent` scope's function

```
<input type="button" bn="" acts="acts" ng-click="$parent.addaction()" value="Add Action" />
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gM2Hg/1/)

Question 3.
Yes you can, but you need to use a controller

```
animateAppModule.directive('bn', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            acts: '='
        },
        link: function ($scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            $scope.$watch('acts', function (neww, old) {
                console.log(neww)
            }, true)
        },
        controller: function($scope){
            $scope.dosomething = function(){
                console.log('do something')
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gM2Hg/2/)

An overall solution could look like

```
<input type="button" bn="" acts="acts" addaction="addaction()" value="Add Action" />
```

JS

```
animateAppModule.controller('tst', function ($scope) {
    $scope.acts = [];
    $scope.addaction = function () {
        $scope.acts.push({
            a: "a,b"
        })
    }
})

animateAppModule.directive('bn', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        scope: {
            acts: '=',
            addaction: '&'
        },
        link: function ($scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
            $scope.$watch('acts', function (neww, old) {
                console.log(neww)
            }, true);
            iElement.click(function(){
                $scope.$apply('addaction()')
            })
        }
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gM2Hg/4/)

Comment: since angular monitor change's using angular.equals which use === operator ,so to watch complex objects like array you should pass true with watch expression to compare for object equality rather then reference

Comment: The use of `$parent` is a [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell), a symptom of a deeper problem.